# node.js Code completion / intellisense

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, webmatrix-2

I have problem with node.js code completion in webmatrix2/visual studio2012
I have read all of the howtos that I could find I couldn't find a proper solution.

The code completion and intellisense works limited.

Mostly it works on the main modules and objects

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket){
```

and in case of "socket." it doesn't work

or with an other solution, the completion works but intellisense does not.

What am I missing?

I have read about those solutions:

http://holtcode.blogspot.hu/2012/12/typescript-nodejs-development-part-1.html

https://bitbucket.org/kurouninn/node.js-visualstudio-intellisense

Thank you!

Comment: Well, `socket` in your example code is a variable name. How could Intellisense possibly know how you are going to name it?

Comment: Ah, I can't edit my comments so.. not the variable name is the problem but example socket.on() or socket.write() in one case the completion work, but the IDE can't find documentation for the function, or object. And in other case work all fine on the top level, but when I'm in a function just line the above example, not. I think I have some configuration issue in case of Visual Studio, but with Webmatrix I don't have configuraion option and I missing this function very mutch.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I thought that the dot was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

It probably does not answers your question, but this is the better way to use Visual Studio with Node.js.
They already releasing beta access if you sign up.

Visual Node - has special bindings with full support of IntelliSense, Modules and Debugging with nice experience that Visual Studio offers.

http://www.visualnode.info/